# Can server-side Blazor make a rendering delay?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

Imagine I have this component:

```
<input bind-value-oninput="@Name">
<p>Your name is @Name</p>
```

```cs
string _name;
string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => _name = value.ToUpper();
}
```

When I type on the input, is the text is transforming directly to uppercase and showing in the paragraph.

I think (please, correct me if I'm wrong) that server-side Blazor runs the .NET MSIL code on the server and sends the DOM changes via SignalR connection.

The connection to the server can be delayed, specially with poor Internet connections.

In the case of this input, can be transformed to uppercase some seconds after the user input text? In afirmative case, how can I solve it? Only using client-side Blazor?

Comment: Do you ask whether execution can alternate between client-side and server-side depending on the availability and strength of the connection?

Comment: @Issac No, I'm asking about the behavior of Blazor when using server-side hosting model and the connection is bad.

Comment: Your question is actually more about SignalR, i've added the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using server-side Blazor has a couple of drawbacks, which you must take into account, when you have to decide which flavor of Blazor to use. Server-side Blazor is mostly recommended to use on private Intranet network, a for instance, an enterprise network, with a few hundreds of users, accessing the network at the same time. In such a case, you'll experience no rendering delay at all.

Using server-side Blazor on the public Internet can be problematic in that respect (It has other downsides to seriously consider), **and can result in unacceptable delay in rendering**. But if its use is forced upon you, it's essential to search for ways that can mitigate  this issue (rendering delay). As for instance, don't use input event. Use change event instead. An input event is triggered whenever you hit a keyboard button, which result in a call to the server to process the event. But if you use the change event, you may reduce the number of calls to the server.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you document about the others downsides? Thanks you, Issac

Comment: Ok, I found it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0#server-side

Comment: I think there is another issue when holding a key down on the input where any handled code on that input event seems to be blocked until the key is lifted.  I have seen this on my own project.  Also a some point the cursor jumps to a different part of the input (usually the end) and your characters start typing from there.  There maybe two issues here; blocking on held key, and latency.  Either way client side would be preferred option for responsive interactive code.  Luckily you'll be able to switch server to client anyway so happily continue developing on server side.

Comment: You may get a better experience with the keydown event.

Answer (score 3):

The rendering delay on a good/average connection is < 50 ms.

Even on a bad connection you ought to stay well below 1 sec.

When your connection gets so bad that you get above that then there is a reconnect dialog built-in.

But yes, if you want to be always available, also on a very bad connection (or no connection), it would be better to use Client side.

Comment: Thank you! If my Internet connection is bad, I will get constantly the reconnect message and make the navigation imposible?

Comment: Yes. One of the properties of Server-side is "no offline support". I don't know the actual threshold in bandwidth or latency but you do need some Internet.

Comment: Thank you. For me, the two answers are OK and are complementaries.

Comment: @Bohring Have you the official Blazor-server reference that explain what the minimum connection requirement of Blazor Server?